# Usercontrol gets restarted (unload+load) after several hours idle time

Tags: .net, wpf

This is a really odd thing. I have a WPF application that loads a UserControl that only contains some images. Behind the scenes, this application collects data from various PerformanceCounters and writes the data to disk every second. However, if I let the application run over night it will unload and then re-load the user control after approx 9 hours (this is not fixed but around that time). From the stack trace collected in the UserControl_Unloaded event I just see that there was a broadcast to unload...

```
UNLOAD:    at PerformanceCollector.Controls.MenuControl.UserControl_Unloaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastUnloadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
```

I totally cannot see why this happens. CPU and memory are rock solid. Stationary PC is not sleeping or anything. Everything is ticked in VS Exception Settings so no errors happening. There are two weird things here, why is it unloading and why is it loading again? But I'll focus on understanding why it unloads and go from there.

Does anyone have any idea on how to pursue this? I need to find out what's the source of the BroadcastUnloadedEvent. Is there something "idle" behavior in WPF/.NET that I'm missing? Some events I can hook into or monitoring options I can use? Clutching at straws here...

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Does it happen with only one `UserControl` or do other controls/usercontrols have the same effect? Have you tried to test it on another PC(to exclude, that problem is system or hardware dependent)? Are image sources locally or on the net?

Comment: There is only 1 user control. Images are local and not using BitMapCache. Seems not related to screen-lock or anything. I have not yet tried it on another PC but will try this weekend and get back...also I want to find out more precisely about the timing (e.g. how many hours to reproduce, does moving the application after 5 hours reset that time etc). I'll get back with more info - just would have been nice if I could hook into something and see what triggers the BroadCastunloadedEvent!!

Comment: @Rekshino the issue seems to be confined to my development PC. I suspect something with DirectX as Windbg shows a DirectX exception just before the controls reloads. I know how to deal with this and since its only on my PC I will manage. Thanks for commenting.